# Install Red5 server in the cloud with Windows Azure?

Tags: java, azure, red5

I've made a virtual machine in Windows Azure. Installed Java SE 6 build 33 JDK, Installed Red5 server version 0.9.1 (the latest version 1.0 rc2 did not work).

Now locally the red5 server works perfectly. I installed a demo and that is working fine. If I want to call the Red5 server from another machine I can't get that to work.

I enter the public IP address from the virtual machine in the red5.properties file. I've setup the firewall to open ports: 1935, 1936, 1945, 5080, 8088 and I've setup the same endpoints in Windows Azure.

If I call the public IP with the port 5080 (http://168.63.23.20:5080) nothing happends.. Not even the standard Red5 homepage. If I call the IP without post 5080 IIS shows the standard IIS homepage so the machine can be called from the internet.

Anyone knsows what I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using internal IP address on the same VM with port (i.e. run ipconfig/ifconfig to get local IP and then try localIP:5080) to confirm the correct configuration.  Run Netmon in your VM to check if incoming requests are hitting to your VM and if not your endpoint configuration need some work.

Comment: With the local IP address it is working. I can't find good old netmon on my Windows 2008 VM. Found a fancy windows netmon app but I don't now what to read there.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know whether you have created an endpoint on the portal. Firewall alone is not enough. It is also needed an endpoint. Please refer to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/ for more details.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Yes I have.. I've created endpoints for all these ports: 1935, 1936, 1945, 5080, 8088.

Comment: This looks like an IT issue instead of a development issue. I suggest you to post the question on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/ as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that after my vacation.

Comment: marcel: same problem here .. did u manage to get it working? :-/